# about uniformly convex Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

Is any uniformly convex Banach space is separable?

If the question is positive, how we can prove it and can I found some examples?

Comment: Uniformly convex Banach spaces are reflexive... So, for uniformly convex $X$, we have: $X$ is separable if and only if the dual $X^*$ is separable.

Comment: Why isn't any answer accepted?

Answer (score 2):

No! Every Hilbert space is uniformly convex and there are non-separable Hilbert spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Each inner product space is  uniformly convex. There are Hilbert spaces, which are not separable.

Conclusion ?

Comment: can we find a relation between separable banach spaces and uniformly convex ones

Comment: @salma, no, there is no relation.

Comment: Uniform convexity is a measure of smoothness of the norm and separability is about smallness of the space. There is absolutely no connection between these.